# printing the Decimal Value from table to CSV File

Tags: java, excel, csv, filewriter

//Java Code to export as CSV the using FileWriter.

```
Java Code :

FileWriter fileWriterForCsv;
fileWriterForCsv.append(4.500);
fileWriterForCsv.append(",");
fileWriterForCsv.append("Mani");
fileWriterForCsv.append(",");
fileWriterForCsv.append("March");
```

// Content of the CSV File Exported mentioned below
    Generated CSV
    ______________

```
Actual Result : 4.5,Mani,March

Expected Result : 4.500,Mani,March

Please let me know whether i need to change the java code??  or how to proceed to get the expected result as above mentioned
```

Also tried to change the column type as text in CSV template. Not getting the expected result.

Comment: Maybe `fileWriterForCsv.append("4.500");` ? You could also use a formatting function to achieve the three trailing zeroes.

Comment: Can u publish a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the number output. This should write the whole line with a CRLF at the end.

```
fileWriterForCsv.format("%.3f,%s,%s%n", 4.5, "Mani", "March");
```